# PdfDocument problem with loading font file - Java

Tags: java, itext

I have a problem when generating a PDF document in Java. When running in an IDE environment, everything works. However, when I build the .exe I get error "css/Montserrat-Regular.ttf not found" and PDF is not created
I also tried to delete css/, I tried to put the font file in the same folder where the class is

And font file is included in build. I am using "Intellij Idea IDE"

Imports:

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.0.4'

import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
```

I tried this

```
static PdfFont regular, bold;

URL font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("css/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
        try (InputStream is = font_path.openStream()) {
            byte[] bytes = StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(is);
            regular = PdfFontFactory.createFont(bytes, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);

        }
```

or this

```
            String link1 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("css/Montserrat-Regular.ttf").getPath();
        regular = PdfFontFactory.createFont(link1, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

Even this not work

```
regular = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_BOLD, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

And this

```
        String path1 = (CreatePDFInvoice.class.getClassLoader().getResource("css/Montserrat-Regular.ttf").getPath());
        regular = PdfFontFactory.createFont(path1, "Identity-H", true);
```

This is part of code:

```
try {

        String link1 = CreatePDFKUF.class.getClassLoader().getResource("css/Montserrat-Regular.ttf").getPath();
        String link2 = CreatePDFKUF.class.getClassLoader()..getResource("css/Montserrat-Bold.ttf").getPath();

        // This dialog is executed
        Functions.showOKdialogSimple("Upute", null, link1);

        // executed - error
        regular = PdfFontFactory.createFont(link1, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);

       
        String folder = Functions.odabranaFirma.getNaziv();
        String subfolder = "KIF";
        String filename = Functions.odabranaFirma.getPDV_broj() + "_" + poreskiPeriod;
        theDir = new File("C:\\CSV_PDV\\" + folder + "\\" + subfolder + "\\");

        System.out.println(theDir.getPath());

        if (!theDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Kreiraj");
            theDir.mkdirs();
        }

        String path = "C:/CSV_PDV/" + filename + "_" + LocalDate.now() + "_" + String.valueOf(Functions.getTime()).replace(":", "") + ".pdf";
        System.out.println("Naziv datoteke " + path);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(path);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());

        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);


        PageXofY event = new PageXofY(CreatePDFKUF.class, pdfDocument);
        pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, event);


        setHeader(document);
        setDetails(document, poreskiPeriod);
        setTable(document, kufs);
        document.add(sp);
        document.add(sp);
        UnitValue pagesize = document.getWidth();
        System.err.println(pagesize + " page size");


        event.writeTotal(pdfDocument);
        document.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // This exception is executed
        Functions.showOKdialogSimple("Greška", null, e.getMessage());

    }
```

[image: First dialog]
[image: Error dialog]

Comment: Have you checked the compiled application where it contains the font resource?

Comment: the font file is also there in the css folder.  I tried putting it in the root folder as well and I get the same error.  I create a File based on that path, I don't get an error.  so it is included in the application

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the issue and show which code line in your code is indicated therein?

Comment: I edited the question, I marked where I get the error

Comment: Also if I totaly remove external fonts I catch exception "Invalid font type"  on first paragraph

Comment: You show where you catch the exception but not where it is thrown. Can you also output the stack trace in your`catch` block?